# How to retrieve all requested params in .NET Web API 2?

Tags: asp.net-web-api

If I want to konw what has been sent through my service, how can I get all the request parameters in Web Api2 Controller as what `Request.Form.ToString()` get in aspx or ashx?

[image]

The Request object is just not the Httpcontext.Request...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public HttpResponseMessage Post(HttpRequestMessage req)
{
    var content = req.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
    return null;
}
```

Also note that the request body is a non-rewindable stream; it can be read only once, you can't call `ReadAsStringAsync()` multiple times.